# How would I split up and store a math expression with a StringTokenizer?

Tags: java, string, math, stringtokenizer

This is my first time working with StringTokenizers, so I am a bit lost on what to do.

My question is just what was asked, How would I split up and store the parts of a mathematic expression as variables using a StringTokenizer?

I need the first number, operator, and second number as separate pieces I can work with, but I do not know how to do that.

I thought of using just doing

```
while(problem.hasMoreTokens()){
     String firstNumber = problem.nextToken();
     String operator = problem.nextToken();  
     String secondNumber = problem.nextToken();
}
```

but this doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing with delimeters.

Any guidance?

UPDATE: I just mean the basic operators like + - / *
and its also just one digit numbers, so like 1+2 for example

Comment: Depends on what operators you're considering.  There are tons of math ops (differentiation, integration, multiplication, division, vector operations, etc.).  You may want to further specify your problem to receive better help.  Also, are you considering this to be a "symbolic manipulator" that handles things like `2*x`, or just numeric calculations?

Comment: From the Javadoc for StringTokenizer - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308481/how-can-tokenize-this-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't. You would write yourself a proper scanner class, that recognizes numbers and operators and that ignores whitespace. You can't do this properly with a `StringTokenizer,` or `String.split(),` or a regular expression for that matter either.

Comment: Then how would I approach doing this with a scanner?

Answer (score 0):

This works, but may or may not be what you need to use (following the answer of Alan Moore, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309024/3088138, to a similar question)

```
String expr ="(X^10-0.9^10)*(X^10-1.1^10)";   

String ops = "[+\\-\\*/\\^\\(\\)]";
String[] tokens = expr.split("(?<="+ops+")\\s*|\\s*(?="+ops+")");

for(String tok: tokens){
  System.out.println("|"+tok+"|");
}
```

It uses [Look-Ahead and Look-Behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split at single-Character operators without losing those operators as tokens.

```
Look-ahead
b(?=a) match any b followed by a
b(?!a) match any b not followed by a

Look-behind
(?<=a)b match any b that is preceded by an a
(?<!a)b match any b that is not preceded by a
```

The result of the code above is

```
||
|(|
|X|
|^|
|10|
|-|
|0.9|
|^|
|10|
|)|
|*|
|(|
|X|
|^|
|10|
|-|
|1.1|
|^|
|10|
|)|
```

so that, when parsing, one has to check for and skip over empty tokens.