# Unable to read string to end in JAVA

Tags: java, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I am trying to make a program that depicts lexical analysis in JAVA. I am able to define token and set everything but I am having an issue reading the whole string inputted in while loop. I want the string to pass through every step in do while but I am unable to achieve them. If i try to do it without do while obviously it does not give accurate result. How to read the string till the end in the while?

```
do {
            if (string.contains("+")) {
                lex_air[0]++;
            } else if (string.contains("-")) {
                lex_air[1]++;
            } else if (string.contains("*")) {
                lex_air[2]++;
            } else if (string.contains("/")) {
                lex_air[3]++;
            }
            if (string.contains(">")) {
                lex_log[0]++;
            } else if (string.contains("<")) {
                lex_log[1]++;
            } else if (string.contains("=")) {
                lex_log[2]++;
            } else if (string.contains(">=")) {
                lex_log[3]++;
            } else if (string.contains("<=")) {
                lex_log[4]++;
            }
            if (string.contains("for")) {
                lex_reserve[0]++;
            } else if (string.contains("int")) {
                lex_reserve[1]++;
            } else if (string.contains("while")) {
                lex_reserve[2]++;
            } else if (string.contains("char")) {
                lex_reserve[3]++;
            } else {
                lex_alpha++;
            }
        } while (string.endsWith(""));
```

Comment: a String *always* ends with `""`; the condition on the while loop is simply `true`.

Comment: How do you know you're not reading to the end of the string? It doesn't look like you are ever considering the position at which the token appears.

Comment: Your other bits of code are merely contains methods, so they only need to be called once anyway. You don't even require the while loop at all. It's merely an infinite loop in this case anyway. You'll have to define more of what you're doing here. Are you splitting your string into multiple lines perhaps and then processing the lines? Just use a for loop in that instance after you've split it into multiple lines. Or if you're splitting through based on a particular token, then just loop through the array that you get after your split operation.

Comment: You have to change make the value evaluated for the condition between 2 iterations, otherwise, it is either an infinite loop, or it would not be run (or only once in your case).

Comment: @ManoDestra i am actually trying to generate tokens and for that i have to separate logical characters, arithmetic characters and obviously numbers, chars and some reserve words.

Comment: In which case, you are going to have to locate the first occurrence of any of your tokens in the string from an index. Update your variables accordingly and update the index to the first character after the token. And keep going while you have not exceeded the string's length and that another token can be found. Or you may be able to use a regular expression to do the splitting for you and just loop through each of the internal parts minus the tokens found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "";
        String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
            switch (words[i]) 
            {
            case  "+" :
                lex_air[0]++;
                break;

            case  "-":
                lex_air[1]++;
                break;

            case  "*" : 
                lex_air[2]++;
                break;

            case  "/":
                lex_air[3]++;
                break;

            case  ">":
                lex_log[0]++;
                break;

            case  "<":
                lex_log[1]++;
                break;

            case  "=":
                lex_log[2]++;
                break;

            case  ">=":
                lex_log[3]++;
                break;

            case  "<=":
                lex_log[4]++;
                break;

            case  "for":
                lex_reserve[0]++;
                break;

            case  "int":
                lex_reserve[1]++;
                break;

            case  "while":
                lex_reserve[2]++;
                break;

            case  "char":
                lex_reserve[3]++;
                break;

            default:
                lex_alpha++;
                break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: If I have a String like `k++` then this will simply not work.

Comment: wont you have to add a case for it ?

Comment: If I understood it correctly then `k` should go in `lex_alpha` and `lex_air[0]` should be incremented twice for the above String. Is it not? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I tried to run with your code. It runs fine until i write a piece of code which like A+B and it gives error.

Comment: Yes, it will give error because there is no space in between `A+B`. The similar case what I was discussing above.

Comment: @user2004685 you are right that should be the case but what is does if i put it in default that it increments the lex_alpha and then breaks.

Comment: @AhmedRik Yes, If you want `A+B` to increment the `lex_alpha` then it should run fine.

Comment: @user2004685 i actually tried A + B then it will run fine even in the default case

Comment: @user2004685 so if we write a `case "k++"` for `k++`  we can have lex_alpha++ and lex_air[0]+2 under it. Wont that work ?

Comment: Why downvote? This is a perfectly valid minimal tokenizer. Of course you can and shall optimize the regexp which splits the tokens (or ensure that there are spaces across the tokens with the current regexp). @Renuka, I upvote your answer. Ahmend, depending on your source text, tokenizig can be easy, or really hairy. Consider for example "a+b" which is a string. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308481/how-can-tokenize-this-string-in-java